# Mocha is returning random failures for passing tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js

i'm developing tests for my nodejs project using mocha. I have a main Test.js file with several require statements to include module related tests, i.e:

Test.js:

```
require('./UserTests.js')
require('./ProductTests.js')
require('./OtherModuleRelatedTests.js')
...
```

There are one hundred tests. For some reason i get random failures when running them altogether, however this is not happening if i manually add it.only() to the test and run it separately.

I am starting my App just once.

Did this ever happen to any of you?

Comment: might be that one of the cases mutates test data

Comment: to find the cause, perhaps you can put the test one by one in `Test.js` and see whether it is failed or not.